# Software to diagnose security breaches and protect account access

Tags: windows, web-browser, security, antivirus, diagnostics

In the past few days, several of my accounts on different apps/websites (first Twitter, then Discord) have gotten hacked, posting messages and sending spam messages to my contacts without my knowledge. As soon as I noticed this was happening, the security on these websites kicked in, blocking my account, and I was able to immediately reset my passwords, which seemed to do the trick.

However, now I got another "attack", this time on my Gmail accounts, that I use to login to Twitter, Discord, and dozens of other websites. I started receiving hundreds of "Mail Delivery Subsystem" spam emails. I immediately also changed passwords to both emails, and blocked the senders, but I am not sure what I should do to protect myself from other attacks.

I access my email accounts on all my devices - on my laptop (Windows 10 OS), and my phones (I have an Android and a work iPhone) - and through Google Chrome. Neither of them have any additional security software, other than the built-in security on both devices.
I assumed the security breach would be on my computer, since it accesses more websites, but after running deep security scans with Windows Defender tools over the last few days, no threats were found.

Since this all happened in the span of a few days, I want to take action I can as fast as I can, but I am not sure where to start.
Does anyone have any recommendations on what I could right now with the build-in security tools of Google Chroe and what type of security software I should use to run diagnostics on my devices and protect my accounts (particularly, on my computer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure this classes as a 'software recommendation' as such, but…

First thing to do is enable 2FA [two-factor authentication] on everything you can.
That will halt many attacks in their tracks.
2FA is, in effect, "something I know & something I have" - so just knowing your password isn't enough, unless they've also got your computer or phone.

Check https://haveibeenpwned.com [yes, silly name, but real database] to see if you've been in any known breaches.

For iCloud, check Find My - https://www.icloud.com/find/ - & make sure you recognise all devices associated **and** their current whereabouts.

Beware, though, that many successful "hacks" aren't hacks at all, they're phishing/social engineering attacks. Someone sent you a dodgy 'we need to check your profile' request & you filled it in without checking.
Use auto-fill/keychain/keepass etc on all your devices, all web sites you connect to. If a known site doesn't autofill… be suspicious, it may have spotted something you didn't.
If you get any request to 'check your details' don't click the link unless you can truly confirm it it to where it is supposed to be… `m1crosoft.com` is unlikely to be what you expect; similarly `appleservice.com` or anything else that doesn't end in a known domain name.
If you're unsure, just type the site's known URL directly into your browser, don't click through the link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I checked the link you sent and it would seem the problem has to do with a cyberattack on another platform that led to my information being leaked. I'm still not sure if there's much I can do about it appart from changing my passwords.

Comment: I am confused.  Are you using your email password for a website password ?

Comment: Oops, was on the mobile, the question was for the OP and should have been under the question.